# How to use messageSource bean for processing Hibernate validation messages?

Tags: spring, hibernate, validation

I have this **message source** bean. It works well for getting messages, e.g. from `org.springframework.validation.Validator`.

```
@Bean(name = "messageSource")
public ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {

    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setCacheSeconds(-1);
    messageSource.setFallbackToSystemLocale(false);
    messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    messageSource.setBasename("classpath:/locale/messages");

    return messageSource;
}
```

and I would like to use this bean for processing JSR 349 validation messages for such POJO class:

```
public class AuthorizationRequest {

    @NotEmpty
    //@NotEmpty(message = "validation.notEmpty")
    @JsonProperty("response_type")
    private String responseType;

    @NotEmpty
    //@NotEmpty(message = "validation.notEmpty")
    @JsonProperty("client_id")
    private String clientId;

    @NotEmpty
    //@NotEmpty(message = "validation.notEmpty")
    @JsonProperty("redirect_uri")
    private String redirectUri;

    private String scope;
// the rest omitted
}
```

But error messages from are still (localized) original Hibernate, such `{org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty.message}`. But I would like to use my own error messages. I have tried many options but none of them work.

I would like to remain one message properties file for whole application.

**Question**

Is there some way how to tell Spring to use my messageSource bean?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this is not working(commented lines)? Placing your messages in property file (resources/locale/message.properties) should work...

Comment: It works but I would like to avoid defining message key for all constraints manually.

Comment: oh I misunderstood the question. creating ValidationMessages.properties under /src/main/resources and overriding messages that you want for your own use, like "org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty.message = your message for not empy" should do.

Answer (score 0):

you need follow this format in Resource Bundle file.

ErrorType.className.fieldName = message.

example:

```
public class Call{
@Pattern(regexp = "^(http://|https://)?(www.)?([a-zA-Z0-9]+).[a-zA-Z0-9]*.[a-z]{3}.?([a-z]+)?$")
private String site;
}
```

and just define message in Resource Bundle like this

Pattern.call.site = site address is wrong.